# Why is Visual Studio appending "_1" to my website virtual directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-5

I open a solution containing a website project named "Student" in Visual Studio. It adds a virtual directory to IIS named "Student_1" even though there is no virtual directory named "Student". Any idea why Visual Studio is doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently something was messed up in the .suo file. I deleted it and was able to open the project.

Comment: I work out of two different branches with different codebases. I already had the sites set up in iis, and when I opened the second solution, VS2010 asked me if I wanted to overwrite the site's files. I clicked no, from then on it would always append the _1 suffix, even after I deleted the sites from IIS. Deleting the .suo file fixes this.